# What is most accurate Spatial reference system for calculate Area entire world

Tags: coordinate-system, area, wgs84

I want to know what Spatial reference system is most accurate to calculate area?
I want to use it for entire world (-180,+180,-90,+90 area in WGS84 system) I have every thing ok I only need to reproject my layer to an accurate SRS and calculate area,Can you help me to find most accurate Spatial reference system for calculate Area entire world?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any global equal-area projection will give you a consistent measurement of area on the surface of the Earth.

Comment: Thank you so much.Can you name one of them which is for all over the world?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Equal-area_projections